# Regarding Serial Communication with assembly code 8086

Tags: assembly, x86, serial-port, tasm

On using INT 14H, AX gets set to 600FH and on using the code to send transmit a character, the AH gets set to 80H. I am using DOSBOX-SvnDaum to run Tasm.How should the time out error be resolved? Following is the code....

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 100h
.data
.code
_start:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov ah, 0           ;Initialize opcode
mov al, 11100011b   ;Parameter data.
mov dx, 0           ;COM1: port.
int 14h
again:
   mov  dx, 0           ;Select COM1:
   mov  al, 'm'        ;Character to transmit
   mov  ah, 1           ;Transmit opcode
   int  14h
   jmp again   
mov ah,1
int 21h
END _start
```

Comment: Where is the error appearing?

Comment: In the "again" loop, on using int 14h. Nothing gets sent to COM1 either....

Comment: This means int14h cannot access the com port you are trying to use. It may be in use by the OS. What is your OS that you run the dos box in?

Comment: http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_14-1.html

Comment: Windows 10 @CharlieH

Comment: Please see the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access COM ports directly via 16bit DOS programs running inside Windows.

Here are your options:

1. Use a COM proxy like [this](https://www.adontec.com/commex_e.htm) one.
2. Install a virtual box and run your programs on it under DOS operating system.